# Why is my 2D animation grey in video editing tab?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, color, grease-pencil, 2d, color-management

This is how my animation actually looks like:[image]

But when I add the scene strip in the video editing tab, it's grey, this is how it looks like:[image]

And when I render it:[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

In the Properties panel of the strip, under the View tab > Scene Strip Display, you can select Shading: Material Preview or Rendered. That will show you the original colors.

[image]